# Authortitle with multiple authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, author

Authortitle prints multiple authors references like this:

> *Surname1, name1, name2 surname2 and name3 surname3*

But I don't like the fact that the first author is surname-comma-name. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add some more information about your code and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem and make it easier to help you. Which style do you prefer?

Comment: 1) Add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407). 2) What do you want instead?

Comment: `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` or `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}`. (Assuming your `biblatex` is not older than version 3.3.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 'First Last' order for all names use

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
```

For 'Last, First' you need

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```